# Использование prototype

Tags: javascript

```
function Person() {}
Person.prototype = {
    constructor: Person,
    name: “Nicholas”,
    age: 29,
    job: “Software Engineer”,
    friends: [“Shelby”, “Court”],
    sayName: function () {
        alert(this.name);
    }
};
var person1 = new Person();
var person2 = new Person();
person1.friends.push(“Van”);
alert(person1.friends); //”Shelby,Court,Van”
alert(person2.friends); //”Shelby,Court,Van”
alert(person1.friends === person2.friends); //true
```

Как исправить, чтобы было false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы некорректно используете прототип. Не используйте прототип:

```
function Person() {
    this.name = "Nicholas",
    this.age = 29,
    this.job = "Software Engineer",
    this.friends = ["Shelby", "Court"],
    this.sayName = function () {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}
var person1 = new Person();
var person2 = new Person();
person1.friends.push("Van");
alert(person1.friends); //"Shelby,Court,Van"
alert(person2.friends); //"Shelby,Court"
alert(person1.friends === person2.friends); //false
```

Comment: В каких случаях нужно поступать именно так?

Comment: Всегда, когда требуется создать свой новый тип данных( класс, структуру ) с уникальным доступом.

Comment: Огромное спасибо.